# Cannot get array from JSON string

Tags: arrays, json

I have a JSON string:

```
"order-lines":{
   "@type":"array",
   "order-line": {
      "id":{"@type":"integer","$":"4164136"},
      "created-at":{"@type":"dateTime","$":"2018-05-10T16:06:16-07:00"},
      ....
   }
}
```

since order-lines here is of type arrary, therefore I expect "order-line" should be an arrary containing multiple order lines, like -

```
"order-line" : [
   {
     "id":{"@type":"integer","$":"4164136"},
     ...
   }
]
```

But as you see in the first json string, there is no array inside "order-lines", it is simply a "order-line" object. Why? How can I parse this into a java array object?

Comment: it's unfortunately common for JSON to be emitted with single-item-arrays collapsed into the one value therein.

Comment: So you mean "order-line" could be an array with more than one item, and could be one value if only one item? That inconsistency could cause trouble when I map this to a java class, because I am always expecting an array for "order-line".

Comment: "Why?" The only people who can answer this are those responsible for the code that generated the JSON. But likely because they made a mistake at serialisation (treating it like XML, which can have multiple daughter tags of the same name). If so, you can't restore it, because all but one value in the "array" are lost.

Comment: I suspect it's the default behavior of some moderately popular JSON encoder to save those two bytes of `[]` - if you (or anyone else) have control of a data source which does this - fix it.  Your first block looks like a JSON-formatted specification (https://json-schema.org/ ?), not a sample data set.